# Configuring update-rc.d script for startup only

Tags: boot, startup, yocto

I'm running Yocto Poky and have a test script I want to run on startup only.  The script just appends date to a file `echo $(date) >> ~/test.txt`.  I add it to the daemon with:

```
update-rc.d -f test.sh start 99 2 3 4 5 .
```

Now when I reboot starting with an empty `test.txt` file, when the system comes back I see 2 lines, timed nearly 2 mins apart.  What am I getting wrong here?